# How can i call AnimateScroll plugin when page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using a plugin in my site called [AnimateScroll](https://github.com/ramswaroop/animatescroll.js), it works fine but I want the page to scroll to the element (with effects) as and when the page loads.

I tried the following code:

```
$(
  $("#element-id").animatescroll();
);
```

But its not working?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for [DOM ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is to wrap your code inside`$(document).ready(function() {...})` or `$(function() {....});` not `$();`, so you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element-id").animatescroll();
});
```

or:

```
$(function() {
    $("#element-id").animatescroll();
});
```

Comment: tried with 2nd option, still doesn't work, any clues?